# Recursively check validity of dict and list item types with requirements

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types

NOTE: It would be great to find a more precise name for this question

Recently, I had to make a script that validate a dictionary structure. This dictionary structure could be composed of some other list or dictionarys structures inside, or basic types with any value (`dict`, `list`, `str` and `int`). Some keys are required, and some others are optional. Here is an example :

```
dictionary = {
    "key1" : required({
        "key1.1": optional([
            required(int),
            required(str),
            optional(str),
            required(int)
            ]),
        "key1.2": required(int)
        }),
    "key2" : optional(int),
    "key3" : required([
            optional(int),
            optional(str),
            required(int)
            ]),
    "key4" : optional(dict),  # Dictionary of any kind allowed
    }
```

Here are some example of valid / invalid dictionary

```
# valid
d1 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 3}, "key2": 42, "key3": ["toto", 42]}

# invalid (because of the order in the list of d["key3"])
d2 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 3}, "key2": 42, "key3": [42, "toto"]}

# valid
d3 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 3, "key1.1": [3, "toto", 12]}, "key3": [42]}

# invalid (because of invalid type of d["key2"]
d4 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 3}, "key2": "bad type", "key3": [42]}

# invalid (missing d["key1"] required)
d5 = {"key3": [42]}

# valid (any kind of dictionary is allowed in key4)
d6 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 42}, "key3": [42], "key4": {}}

# valid (any kind of dictionary is allowed in key4)
d7 = {"key1": {"key1.2": 42}, "key3": [42], "key4": {"poney": "amazing"}}
```

My implementation of `required` and `optional` just return a tuple with a boolean indicating if the item is required. It can be modified.

```
def required(entity):
    return (True, entity)

def optional(entity):
    return (False, entity)
```

**Objective:** make a function which take as parameter the dictionary to check (`d1`, `d2`, `d3`...) and the validator (`dictionary`), and return a boolean that indicate if the dictionary is valid or not.

I made a part of script that validate a dictionary structure, but it is long and doesn't validate the list structures (like `dictionary["key1"]["key1.1"]`, i'm stuck on that). I can post it here, but I feel like it would just polute the topic...

Comment: You can solve this by considering your allowed dictionary structures sentences of a prescribed grammar, and hence validate it with a recursive descent parser the way compilers do.

Comment: It looks like a good idea. I'll work on that.